# Communicating between two webviews with Javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, webview

In an application that has multiple webviews, is there any way to have the JavaScript in two separate webviews communicate with each other directly? I would really like to use JavaScript in one webview to control the contents of the other webview, but my bet is that each environment is completely isolated and that communication has to be serialized and sent through the webview controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<frameset>`, `<iframe>` etc in the same web view to communicate between two pages.

Otherwise, there's no way to see outside of the environment (esp. for iPhoneOS since the whole WebKit framework is a private API.)

Comment: Shoot. That's too bad. At the heart of my problem is that I need multiple webviews, each that can scroll independently. Right now, I'm using one wide webview that has side-to-side scrolling managed by a scroll controller to move between "pages" of data and up-and-down scrolling controlled by the webview. Side-to-side works smoothly, but up-and-down is very, very difficult to control. I was thinking of serializing the HTML fragments and passing them via the webview controller to the webviews that need them, but binding events is going to be very difficult to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the same thing and came across this thread in researching the problem. Haven't had a chance to model it yet, but looks like it's at least theoretically feasible by first using JavaScript to communicate with the Objective-C wrapper, and then sending that data over to the second WebView via a JavaScript call. Info on each of these two (independent) steps can be found here: http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/

Comment: With Objective C, we ended up staying with a single webview. But using the application as proxy does work. I ended up doing this in Android (creating a MessageCenter object that directs messages between the various webviews.  In iOS, if you are communicating with the application layer by changing the URL, one thing you need to be very careful of is to space out the messages. If you set the URL twice in rapid succession, usually only the last URL will get picked up. It's best to write a queue in JavaScript and have the application advance the queue when it's ready to receive new messages.